# WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state - HTML

Tags: python, html, websocket

I'm new to HTML5/javascript I've created a websocket server using python.
I want to view the data & add up the received messages in a text area, not sure what's going wrong, but it works fine on the first attempt to send a message but throws a "`WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state`" while sending another.

Am I missing something from html ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
  var connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765");
  
  connection.onopen = function () {
   console.log('Connection Opened');
  };

  connection.onerror = function (error) {
   console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
  };

  connection.onmessage = function (e) {
   document.getElementById("rxConsole").value += e.data;
  };
 
  function sendMessage(msg){
   console.log('I\'m sending data');
   connection.send(document.getElementById("txBar").value);
   document.getElementById("txBar").value = "";
  }
</script>

   
  
   </head>
   <body">
   <div>
   <textarea id="rxConsole"></textarea
 </div>
 <hr/>
 <div>
  <input type ="text" id="txBar" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) sendMessage();" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Python code :

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

From chrome:

[image]